# Why does adding a zero before a number change its value?

Tags: javascript

Write out 074 in the console and it'll return 60.

```
074
>>60
```

Why?

Comment: Numbers with a leading zero are octal, just like numbers with leading `0x` are hex.

Comment: I agree with @Niet the Dark Absol... if you want to get 074 write into console "074" like a string...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a zero before a number tells javascript to interpret it as an octal (base 8) value.

According to the [MDN documentation on number literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Decimal_numbers), you can use the following to represent numbers on different base:

- **decimal**: numbers starting with any digit other than zero are decimal.
- **binary**: numbers starting with `0b` or `0B`
- **octal**: numbers starting with `0`
- **hexadecimal** starting with `0x` or 0X`
- **exponentiation** ending with `e` followed by a number (`1e3` = 1x10<sup>3</sup>)